# handle edit action in a data table

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

I have a form with 3 input fields and two command buttons(Submit and Cancel). Once the user submits the form, the information should be populated in the data table below with 3 columns.There is also a action column with EDIT and DELETE command links for each row inserted. On click of EDIT, the information for that record needs to be populated to the form above and then if the form is submitted, check if the record already exists. If the record doesn't exists, then add it to the list.

XHTML1 
    
                    
                        FirstName:

```
                    <h:outputLabel>LastName:</h:outputLabel>
                    <h:inputText id="lastName" value="#{form.lastName}"/>

                    <h:outputLabel>MiddleName:</h:outputLabel>
                    <h:inputText id="middleName" value="#{form.middleName}" />

                    <h:commandButton value="Cancel" action="#{formBacking.cancel}" immediate="true"></h:commandButton>
                    <h:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{formBacking.submit}"></h:commandButton>

                </h:panelGrid>

            </h:form>
```

XHTML2

### User Details

```
            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">FirstName</f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{userDetails.fname}" />
            </h:column>

            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">LastName</f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{userDetails.lname}" />
            </h:column>

            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">MiddleName</f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{userDetails.mName}" />
            </h:column>

            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">Action</f:facet>
                <h:commandLink
                    action="#{formBacking.editUser(userDetails)}"
                    value="Edit" />
                <h:commandLink
                    action="#{formBacking.deleteUser(userDetails)}"
                    value="Delete" />
            </h:column>

        </h:dataTable>
    </h:form>

 Form.java
    @Managed Bean
    @ViewScoped
    private String firstName = "";
    private String lastName = "";
    private String middleName = "";
    //Setters and getters

    UserBacking.java

    @ManagedBean
    @ViewScoped

    private List<Form> userList = new ArrayList<Form>();
    \\setters and getters

    public void submit(){}
    public void cancel(){}
    public void editUser(){}
    public void deleteUser(){}

What would be the best way to handle the edit functionality?
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `rich:modalpanel` for action of edit and delete.  I guess You knows about that.
It will show you a popup which also has an `actionListener` method, by using that action listener method you can configure your checks like record exists or not.

Answer (score 1):

Use a session scoped Managed bean .

At first time show the list of users in a data table . make your User firstName field a command link so when clicking it the correspondent user details page us rendered and in this page you can add your CRUD (edit,delete... functionnalities).

```
<p:dataTable border="1" value="#{gestionUtilisateurMB.usersList}" 
                     var="userObj"
                     paginator="true" rows="10"  
                     paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink}      
    {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}   
      {RowsPerPageDropdown}"  
                     rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15"
                     rowIndexVar="rowIndex"
                      binding="#{table}">
                        <p:column id="column1">
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText 
        value="Login"></h:outputText>
                            </f:facet>


                              <h:commandLink action="#
      {gestionUtilisateurMB.showUserDetails}" value="#{userObj.name}">  
                                 <f:setPropertyActionListener 
       target="#{gestionUtilisateurMB.selectedUserRow}" value="#{userObj}" />
                                 <f:setPropertyActionListener target="# 
         {gestionUtilisateurMB.selectedUserRow.dbRowIndex}" value="#{table.rowIndex}"/>

                              </h:commandLink>  

                        </p:column>
                        <p:column id="column2">
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText 
            value="Name"></h:outputText>
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:outputText value="#
            {userObj.lastName}"></h:outputText>
                        </p:column>

                         <p:column id="column3">
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText id="text3" 
            value="First Name"></h:outputText>
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:outputText value="#
              {userObj.firstName}"></h:outputText>
                         </p:column>

                          <p:column id="column4">
                              <f:facet name="header">
                         <f:facet name="footer">  
                          </f:facet> 

                </p:dataTable>
```

User Details :

```
 <h:panelGrid id="display" header="User Detail" columns="2" cellpadding="4">  

                           <f:facet name="header">  
                              <p:graphicImage value="/src/main/resources/images/users
   /user.png"/>  
                           </f:facet>   
                            <h:outputText value="rowIndex:" />  
                            <h:outputText value="#
        {gestionUtilisateurMB.selectedUserRow.dbRowIndex}" /> 

                            <h:outputText value="Login:" />  
                            <h:outputText value="#
        {gestionUtilisateurMB.selectedUserRow.name}" />  

                            <h:outputText value="Name:" />  
                            <h:outputText value="#
          {gestionUtilisateurMB.selectedUserRow.lastName}" />  

                            <h:outputText value="First Name:" />  
                            <h:outputText value="#
             {gestionUtilisateurMB.selectedUserRow.firstName}" />  

                            <h:outputText value="Email:" />  
                            <h:outputText value="#
            {gestionUtilisateurMB.selectedUserRow.email}" />  

                            <h:outputText value="Phone:" />  
                            <h:outputText value="#
                  {gestionUtilisateurMB.selectedUserRow.phoneNumber}" />  
                     </h:panelGrid>
```